# Profile:edit, no redirection

Tags: structure, profile-edit

The {exp:profile:login return="profile/edit"} doesn't work as expected : the page doesn't redirect on submit. The template_group/template exist, I can access this page via the template manager and it renders correctly.
 I'm using "structure", the profile channel isn't managed by the module.

The EE login form works.

Well, I'm … lost :(

Any idea ? Please ?

Comment: Can you please show the EE tag you are using in its entirety?

Profile:Edit has had some issues for me when I use an .htaccess file to add a '/' to the end of my urls, you might want to check in to that as well.

Comment: Sounds very peculiar indeed. What version of Profile:Edit are you using and what version of EE are you using?

Comment: I use the exact same tag as in the profile:edit doc.No .htaccess. As I said, if I replace this tag by EE login tag, it works correctly. What's the difference between the two ? Can I use EE tag with no issue ?

Comment: I'd say to update to the latest version of Profile Edit if you're not already using it but by the looks of things MightyBigRobot have shut up shop completely and their site is no longer their. The last version I had was 1.0.9. It may be a bug but it uses the exact parameters as Safecracker forms so I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work. What's your EE version?

Comment: I'm already using profile edit 1.0.9 with EE 2.5.5
Thanks for your time !

Comment: Hmmm. I'll see if I can re-create the issue and will get back to you with the findings. If you can provide a sample of your login form that would be useful to try and recreate as closely as possible.

Comment: Oh, by the way, you don't have the Pages module installed too do you?

Comment: No, I'm not using the Pages module (not with structure). For the code, it's the same that the ee login form, just replace the ee part (exp:member:login_form) by profile:edit syntax. By the way, profile:edit isn't supported anymore by Chris Newton ??

Comment: I ran into this issue as well. Josh KG's answer seems to have fixed this for now.

Answer (score 3):

I’m using 2.5.5 and 1.09 and I’m also experiencing this problem with the return parameter.

When I check the rendered form markup I can see this in the HiddenFields `div`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="http://domain.com/templategroup/template">
```

Whereas that value is just the path to the template where I’m using the `profile:edit:login` tag.

and below that:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="group/template">
```

Wherein the value is exactly the content entered in my `return=` parameter in the `profile:edit:login` tag.

For anyone else experiencing this problem, here’s a hacky fix:

If you drop in a duplicate of the `RET` hidden input right before the close your `profile:edit:login` tag, the page will use that instead of the broken p:e generated one.

```
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="{path="group/template"}">
```

Comment: Thanks for offering a temporary solution to this problem!